# What are the possible ways of playing video stored in firebase database for android?

Tags: android, firebase, video, firebase-realtime-database

How I could playback a video I stored in firebase database in android?  Below is the code I have tried without success:

```
public class PostDetailActivity extends BaseActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

private static final String TAG = "PostDetailActivity";

public static final String EXTRA_POST_KEY = "post_key";

private Context mApplicationContext = this;

private DatabaseReference mPostReference;
private DatabaseReference mCommentsReference;
private ValueEventListener mPostListener;
private String mPostKey;
private CommentAdapter mAdapter;

private MediaController mediaController;

private TextView mAuthorView;
private TextView mTitleView;
private TextView mBodyView;
private VideoView mMediaVideo;
private ImageView mMediaView;
private EditText mCommentField;
private Button mCommentButton;
private RecyclerView mCommentsRecycler;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_post_detail);

    // Get post key from intent
    mPostKey = getIntent().getStringExtra(EXTRA_POST_KEY);
    if (mPostKey == null) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Must pass EXTRA_POST_KEY");
    }

    // Initialize Database
    mPostReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference()
            .child("posts").child(mPostKey);
    mCommentsReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference()
            .child("post-comments").child(mPostKey);

    // Initialize Views
    mAuthorView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.post_author);
    mTitleView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.post_title);
    mBodyView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.post_body);
  //    mMediaView = (ImageView) findViewById(imageView);
    mMediaVideo = (VideoView) findViewById(videoView);
    mCommentField = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.field_comment_text);
    mCommentButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_post_comment);
    mCommentsRecycler = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recycler_comments);

    mCommentButton.setOnClickListener(this);
    mCommentsRecycler.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));

}

@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();

ValueEventListener postListener = new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            // Get Post object and use the values to update the UI
            Post post = dataSnapshot.getValue(Post.class);
        //   Picasso.with(mApplicationContext).load(post.getMsgUrl()).resize(600, 400).onlyScaleDown().into(mMediaView);
                mMediaVideo.setVideoURI(Uri.parse(post.getMsgUrl()));
                    mMediaVideo.requestFocus();
                    mMediaVideo.start();
            mTitleView.setText(post.title);
            mBodyView.setText(post.body);
        }
   }
}
```

I do not received any error report when I run the programme. I have tried extensive search for any possible solution without success. I am wondering if firebase was not built for such function.

Comment: All you have here is a listener, which doesn't do anything on  it's own. So where do you actually use that?

Comment: And it looks like you are storing links to videos, not video files themselves

Comment: @cricket_007 inside the listener is where I think I am having problem because, when I comment out the video and substitute it with image for  example; `Picasso.with(mApplicationContext).load(post.getMsgUrl()).resize(600, 400).onlyScaleDown().into(mMediaView);` , the image is displayed correctly. Thanks for your timely reply.

Comment: Please show a [mcve] of all your code

Comment: Ok. I will do that in just a while.

Comment: Pls. I have updated my code above. Thanks.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/143656/discussion-between-aika-and-cricket-007).